# Do device drivers communicate with each other, or are they asynchronously called?

Tags: user-interface, process, operating-system, device-driver, multitasking

I will paint an example of what I am asking in crystal clear detail.

Say we are in a typical userland app, like painting software or text editing, and we decide to hover the mouse or click a combo box. From this input alone the mice's trackball will need to be fetched from the device driver on the low-level, but the video driver will also need to update the position of the pointer on the screen accordingly at the (seemingly) same time as follows:

[image]

As the picture illustrates, not moving the mouse, but calling the driver/updating the screen constantly works. However, what if we choose to both click the menu combo box/drop down list, and update the framebuffer feed constantly? Are both drivers called almost at the same time, and what calls them (the GUI desktop, the app directly, etc.). Because the mouse works ANYWHERE, on an app or not ... that makes me question if the mouse input is indefinitely system called, however, video output depends more on what the app is(like below, texpad).

Answer (score 1):

The mouse driver has nothing to do with the video driver. You're getting the distinction wrong between what happens in the kernel space and user space.

The kernel has no idea of a concept of a 'mouse pointer'. It only exports an interface saying, "I have a input device that gives X and Y coordinates". Likewise with the video driver, it only exports an interface saying, "I have a device where you can output pictures" - it doesn't know what a mouse pointer is.

The GUI is all handled in user space and that's where you get the concept of drop down boxes, mouse pointers etc... Whatever program handles your GUI takes the kernel interfaces and does stuff with it, such as associating the input device with a mouse pointer and outputting video to the screen.

How the contents of the screen is actually pushed to the hardware will be driver dependent and doesn't involve user space. The GUI just tells the kernel, "I want the screen to look like this" and the kernel handles the rest.

Both drivers can certainly run in parallel if you have a multi-core CPU but, unless you're implementing the driver or scheduler, you don't need to know the details.